# Почему результат поиска всегда возвращает undefined?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Функция поиска для бота telegram

```
function onSearch(searchString) {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById('12EBocrIPnzd7RejDWGa72fNt4WTznpWFtDh_Z2rMAns').getSheetByName("bot");
  var values = sh.getDataRange().getValues();

  for(var i=0, iLen=values.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if(values[i][2] === searchString) {

      return values[i][3];}}}

var search = contents.message.from.id; ;
      sdata = onSearch(search);
      sendText(id_message, "Дата" + sdata  +  ");
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12EBocrIPnzd7RejDWGa72fNt4WTznpWFtDh_Z2rMAns/edit#gid=0

Должно возвращать дату в том же ряду в котором нашло id пользователя.

Как я не кручу поиск всё время возвращает undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего вести документацию к коду и не делать многозадачных функций

```
/**
 *
 * @param {string | number} searchString
 * @return {date}
 */
function onSearch(searchString) {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    '12EBocrIPnzd7RejDWGa72fNt4WTznpWFtDh_Z2rMAns'
  ).getSheetByName('Аркуш1');
  var values = sh.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 0, iLen = values.length; i < iLen; i++)
    if (values[i][2] == searchString) return values[i][3];

  return new Date(0);
}

/**
 *
 */
function test_onSearch() {
  console.log('4938127', onSearch('4938127'));
  console.log(4938127, onSearch(4938127));
  console.log('xxx', onSearch('xxx'));
  console.log(undefined, onSearch(undefined));
}
```

Как видно, `onSearch` на вход получает строку или число, возвращает дату. Тестирование проводим с невалидными значениями без крайних

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если у вас включен V8, то

```
/**
 *
 * @param {string | number} searchString
 * @return {date}
 */
function onSearch(searchString) {
  const rowData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    '12EBocrIPnzd7RejDWGa72fNt4WTznpWFtDh_Z2rMAns'
  )
    .getSheetByName('Аркуш1')
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues()
    .find(row => row[2] == searchString);

  return !rowData ? new Date(0) : rowData[3];
}
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, если не сложно подскажите еще пожалуйста а почему мы возвращаем new Date(0) и оно выдает нам значение из тиблицы, а не новую дату?

Comment: @Jeen, `new` - потому что `Date` стандартный класс. А возвращаем мы начальную дату для совместимости. Используя [тернарный оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80), функция вернет нулевую дату, если `rowData` не существует, и значение из Таблицы, если значение есть.

Comment: @Jeen, если это решение, то нужно отметить как решение.